# Core Data in XCode 5 - installing manually and how?

Tags: xcode, core-data

It seems like that in the new version of XCode, Core Data is something i have to install manually. The check box that used to be there when i create a new project is gone.

I've searched to the end of the internet, finding no answer that seems to work in the new version of XCode. Can someone confirm my problem, and does someone have a solution for it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Core Data checkbox is not available in all type of projects. If you try to create an empty project, the "Use core data" checkbox is still there (this was the same in xcode 4).

You can add core data manually by following this tutorial:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/

Comment: Can you confirm that this 4 year old tutorial will work with XCode 5? I tried a very similar example, unfortunately with no success.

Comment: I haven't give it a try with Xcode 5 but it probably will. It is better though to start with a project template that allows core data enabling during project set up.

Comment: @PriyanHaridas Do yourself a favour and don't put the setup code in the AppDelegate. Put it in the first view controller that uses a managed object context.

Comment: Also `Use Core Data` checkbox available for "Master-Detail Application" and "Utility Application".

Comment: @Abizern any reason why you shouldn't put the properties and functions in AppDelegate?

Comment: @annaFortuna have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1 in the section on "Getting a managed object context" - it makes the application rigide

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new master-detail Xcode project (check the 'use core data' checkbox when creating) and just copy the code from there.

this is particularly helpful when combined with:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/